# Macro para Doble buscarv en visual basic

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Tengo una macro de un Buscarv que me funciona perfectamente, pero quiero potenciarla, en ves de poner error o vacio que es mi caso quisiera poder hacer otro buscarv pero de otra hoja del mismo archivo, algun truco?

```
Sub busquedaVertical() 
Dim cont As Long
Dim ultLinea As Long
Dim ValorPrima As Variant
Dim Poliza As Variant
Dim rango As Variant

ultLinea = Sheets("R5").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rango = Sheets("AXA-web").Range("A:F")

For cont = 2 To ultLinea
    Poliza = Sheets("R5").Cells(cont, 4)
    ValorPrima = Application.VLookup(Poliza, rango, 6, False)

    If IsError(ValorPrima) Then
        ValorPrima = 0
    End If

     Sheets("R5").Cells(cont, 5) = ValorPrima
Next cont
end sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Bienvenido a SO.

Mi recomendación es que antes uses CONTAR.SI para comprobar si el valor buscado (`Poliza`) existe en primer rango. Si la cuenta devuelve 0, significa que NO existe, y entonces haces un BUSCARV en el segundo. Si la cuenta es mayor que 0, puedes hacer BUSCARV en el primer rango.

[CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO (función CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO)](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/contar-si-conjunto-funci%C3%B3n-contar-si-conjunto-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842)

En programación en VBA, CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO se dice COUNTIFS, que es lo que vamos a usar.

Yo he hecho un ejemplo muy sencillo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y mi código es éste:

```
Sub test()

Dim ValorBuscado As Long
Dim MiResp As String

ValorBuscado = InputBox("numero del 1 al 6", , 1)

With Application.WorksheetFunction
    If .CountIfs(Range("A1:A3"), ValorBuscado) > 0 Then
        'ValorBuscado está en el primer rango. Hago un BuscarV ahí
        MiResp = .VLookup(ValorBuscado, Range("A1:B3"), 2, 0)
    Else
        'ValorBuscado NO ESTÁ en el primer rango. Hago un BuscarV en el segundo rango
        MiResp = .VLookup(ValorBuscado, Range("D1:E3"), 2, 0)
    End If
End With

MsgBox MiResp

End Sub
```

El código pide un número al usuario. Si el usuario introduce un valor entre 1 y 3, la línea de código `.CountIfs(Range("A1:A3"), ValorBuscado)` devolverá 1, que es mayor que 0, por lo tanto, hará un BUSCARV en el primer rango.

Si el usuario especifica de 4 a 6, la línea `.CountIfs(Range("A1:A3"), ValorBuscado)` devolverá 0, entonces hará el BUSCARV en el segundo rango.

Es mejor de esta manera porque un VLOOKUP en tiempo de ejecución si falla siempre generará un error, y por lo tanto, tienes que estar con *error handling*, atrapándolo y jugando con ello. Creo que es más fácil una doble comprobación, ya que COUNTIFS no va a devolver un error, solo devolverá 0 o un número mayor que 0, sin generar errores. Según ese resultado, haces VLOOKUP en un sitio u otro.

Espero que sirva.